# jenkins job hangs when we are redirecting stderr

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline job to remove some docker images and i have written script in python as below.

```
cat <<EOF > fabfile.py
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
import os
env.use_shell=False
env.password = os.environ['DEPLOY_PASSWORD']

def clean_aws_docker_registry_node_local_registry():
run("df -k")
#sudo("docker rmi -f \$(docker images -q)")
sudo("docker rmi -f \$(docker images -q) 2>/tmp/errors.txt")
run("df -k")
EOF
```

But when i run this job it hangs at docker rmi command and if i remove redirection like 2>/tmp/errors.txt, it is working fine. I can remove redirection but if docker rmi command throws any error then immediately build is showing as failure.

I am running these commands on aws server by logging into it using fab as 
    fab clean_aws_docker_registry_node_local_registry -u ${USERNAME} -H x.x.x.x
Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: If you don't care whether or not your `docker rmi` command actually removes an image (maybe it doesn't exist anymore), you could instead just add `| true` to the end of the command. I do this because I want to remove the images, but don't want the job to fail if some other job has already removed them.

Comment: sudo("docker rmi -f \$(docker images -q) 2>/tmp/errors.txt") | true or
sudo("docker rmi -f \$(docker images -q) 2>/tmp/errors.txt | true") which way is correct.

Comment: It looks like you're using redirection just to keep an issue with your command causing the job to fail. In that case, I would do this: `sudo("docker rmi -f \$(docker images -q)") | true`.